# How does ifstream know where is the delimeter

Tags: c++, visual-c++

so when i readfile("animal.txt") it gave me

```
zebra
baboon
orangutan
gorilla
aardvark
lion
tiger
cougar
ocelot
panther
rat
mouse
gerbil
hamster
elephant
rhinoceros
hippopotamus
```

i would like to know how `ist >> s` identify the delimiter and separate the long string into individual words. I provided a txt and my implementation below .

```
animal.txt


zebrababoonorangutangorillaaardvarkliontigercougarocelotpantherratmousegerbilhamsterelephantrhinoceroshippopotamus
```

and

```
SortedList readFile(string infile)
{
      SortedList result;
      string s;

      ifstream ist(infile.c_str()); // open file
      // Check if file opened correctly
      if(ist.fail()) throw runtime_error("file not found");

      // Read file into list
      while(ist >> s){
          cout<< s << endl;
          cout << ist << endl;
            result.insert(s);
      }

      return result;
}
```

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/ allows you to pass a character as delimiter, for example

Comment: It looks like you incorrectly pasted the contents of animal.txt.

Comment: @aschelper. the txt file it is how it supposed to be.

there one thing i realise. while i paste it on stackoverflow, it automatically show the same as the result. and when im trying to erase the letter in animal.txt it wont you have to press twice on the each word seperation.

Comment: The txt file obviously has some whitespace bytes in it.  Maybe the other program you use to examine animal.txt doesn't show them correctly.  MS Notepad, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

The `operator>>` when applied to a stream on the left and a string on the right.

Will read a "white space" separated word from the stream into the string.

Mote precisely it will:

1. Read and ignore characters until `issapce()` is false.
2. Read and store in the string characters until `isspace()` is true.